# VBA - wildcard in VBA to check format

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a macro to check the format of the date. For this proces it's necessary that the date needs to be in the format: DD-MM-JJJJ. If the user use an other format for example JJJJ-MM-DD the workflow will quit. Therfore i want to build a macro that will give a string in a cell if the format is wrong.

Currently i have the following macro written, but it doens't work. Can someone help me to write the correct macro?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
dim ws as worksheet
set ws = Worksheets("Bugs")

if Worksheets("Data").Range("E14").Value = "**" & "-" & "**" & "-" & "****" Then
ws.range("B1").value = "Correct format"
Else
ws.range("B1").value = "Jou have used wrong format, please use DD-MM-JJJJ"
End if 

End sub
```

I hope someone can help me! If there any questions feel free to ask me.

Comment: you need set workbook before worksheet. add `dim wb as workbook: set wb=thisworkbook` and change `set ws= wb.worksheets("Bugs")` and conditions `if ws.Range("E14") = ...`

Comment: IF you are going to use wild cards in this setting, you need to use the `Like` operator. In the long run, you'd probably be better off ensuring that all dates are "real dates" and working with that value, rather than text representations of dates.

Comment: by the way this condition to check correct date wont work correctly `"**" & "-" & "**" & "-" & "****"` return true for every month introduced before day.this is typical american notation to indroduce month - day - year

Answer (score 0):

If the cell isn't formatted expressly as text, the application considers date entries as `Double` type numbers, but displays them according to the chosen *number format*.

So the simplest way is to compare the exact `Numberformat` property, e.g.`dd-mm-yyyy` via

```
If Sheet1.Range("E14").NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy" Then ...
```

or dates like `10/31 2021` via

```
 If Sheet1.Range("E14).NumberFormat = "mm\/dd yyyy" Then ...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Bugs")
    
    If Worksheets("Data").Range("E14").Value Like "??/??/????" Then
        ws.Range("B1").Value = "Correct format"
    Else
        ws.Range("B1").Value = "Jou have used wrong format, please use DD-MM-JJJJ"
    End If
  
End Sub
```

Comment: As mentioned in comments to the original post, a solution based on just counting the number of characters in the various field is insufficient as it will allow dates such as 10/31/2021 (MM/DD/YYYY)